# Negative offset causes RecyclerView item to disappear

Tags: android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-cardview

In my `RecyclerView`, I have a header image for each group of `CardView`. The image extends below the first card view to create a nice visual effect. I achieved this by creating an image header view holder, and set the offset of the first `CardView` in each group to be negative (using `ItemDecoration`). However, as you can see at the bottom of the screen, the `CardView` disappears before it goes completely offscreen.

[image]

My custom item decoration

```
class OffsetItemDecoration(val offset: Int, val itemPositions: Array<Int>) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)

        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        val layoutManager = parent.layoutManager

        if (!itemPositions.contains(position) || layoutManager !is LinearLayoutManager) {
            return
        }
        outRect.top = offset
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity`:

```
val itemOffset = OffsetItemDecoration(-150, arrayOf(1, 5))
recycler_view.addItemDecoration(itemOffset)
```

Recommendations of other ways to achieve the same effect would be appreciated as well

Comment: I'd turn it around and add the image as a decoration on top of the item, giving it a positive offset

Comment: I don't see how setting a positive offset could create overlap effect. Do you mind share some code and post as an answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I have the same issue.